Should we forward people via the tag wiki?
I recently voted to close this question with the tag software-recommendation. Now there's a similar tag named reference-request.
By our policy we don't allow software-recommendations and close them as oppinion based and off-topic, the same goes for reference requests.
Now I'm asking myself: Should we edit the tag-wiki entries of these tags (and others clearly being associated with "disallowed" questions) to forward people using these tags to SR SE or to SO(in case someone looks for a library)?
This would mean that the software-recommendation tag will contain:

Please consider strongly to rather use softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com, as your question is likely to get closed as off-topic / opinion based


Sure, it's a good idea to redirect people to other sites in a tag wiki, when relevant.
But I don't see why we would have a software-recommendation tag at all. This isn't a way that we use to classify question, and a question with that tag would presumably be off-topic anyway.
When you direct someone to Software Recommendations, please always request that they read the question quality guidelines. SR.SE has strong quality requirements: we don't take just any “what's the best library” poll, we want specific questions calling for specific answers like other Stack Exchange site. Also please redirect people to SR.sE only if you have read the guidelines and you can see that the question would be suitable there.
